# Error dropping database (can't rmdir './someDB/', errno: 17)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-server

It's insane. I have tried all the methods but it still throws the same error.

I have a database, want it to run on `MySQL-Server`. At the beginning of the Database:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS someDB;
CREATE SCHEMA someDB;
USE someDB;
```

When I tried `SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'someDB';` it confirms the existence of it.

I tried:

1. `chmod` for the full path to it `/var/lib/mysql/someDB/someDB.sql`
2. Stopping `MySQL-Server`, Deleting the the `someDB` folder and starting the Server again.
3. I removed the entire `MySQL-Server` and reinstalled it again.

After hours of trying, I really need you help.

**EDIT**:
Answering [Y. Collin Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291021/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-somedb-errno-17?noredirect=1#comment81532754_47291021), when I run `sudo ls -la ./someDB`, it returns:

```
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Nov 14 16:53 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 mysql  mysql   4096 Nov 14 16:53 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 12243 Nov 14 16:53 someDB.sql
```

Comment: You have `chmod -R` the someDB dir?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17#4584523

Comment: @Pete I have been following the answers in the link you provided all the day, No luck yet.
And Yes I have changed the privilege recursively.

Comment: Reading between the lines you appear to have dropped your restore file into the directory for the SomeDB schema. That was rather silly. Move it somewhere else. And it shouldn't be owned by mysql, it should be owned by the user you are logged in as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I have a logical mistake.

Inside the `someDB.sql` file, I am using the `USE` statement. However, I am trying to run the database by using this command:

```
mysql -u root -p someDB < someDB.sql
```

Which is absolutely wrong because the above statement prompt the `USE` which conflicts with the first line in the `sql` file (i.e `DROP SCHEMA...`).

The correct way to do it is:

```
mysql -u root -p < someDB.sql
```

because the `USE` statement is placed in the file already!

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if who run the following command:

```
ls -la ./someDB/
```

If there is a file in it like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17) you should delete it first.

Credit to @Beel