# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813 Tablespace for table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

## Am using Laravel 5.6

I Tried to migrate purchases table for my project
When i tried to migrate and it's showing Table Space error.

> General error: 1813 Tablespace for table '`jshop`.`purchases`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.

Migrate Code Below :

```
Schema::create('purchases', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer("product_price");
        $table->integer("product_qty");
        $table->unsignedInteger('invoice_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('weight_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign("invoice_id")->references('id')->on('invoices');
        $table->foreign("product_id")->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->foreign("weight_id")->references('id')->on('weights');
    });
```

## invoice,products,weights table are valid in my database.

Error Message Image Below : 
[Migration Error image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymr9k.jpg)
How to solve this ?

[Full Migration Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeH83.jpg)

Comment: can you share full migrate code?

Comment: Refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694168/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp

Comment: @sanduniYW sir when am trying to put all code its warning me about length of code. That's why  i shared image link below https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeH83.jpg please open this.

Comment: kk..thanks. I add answer below. Plz try it.

Comment: please put the relevant code in the question as text and not an image. this question becomes less useful if the image link goes down...

Comment: @bunbun sir at first i added every single code of this migration. But stack authority showing some error that's y i have to re-edit this code

Comment: Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17/78178172#78178172

Answer (score 10):

Drop the database and create a new one.

Comment: Although this suggestion is not the most elegant solution to the problem, in some cases, it will work.

Comment: It sounds like: "Just reinstall Windows" ))

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

if it is not solve this error
try this:

Go to `mysql/data/database_name /tablename.ibd file` and delete it manually.
after this try your command `php artisan migrate`

Comment: sir... still  facing this problem . :(

Comment: you use xampp or wamp?

Comment: xampp at windows 10 Operating system

Comment: try above solution

Comment: sir it's not work ... when i create new database with different name and migrate this . And its work now. Thank you so much for your help sir... your suggestion really good

Comment: deleting database_name folder inside mysql solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Your database is corrupted, do the followinf steps to fix it.

SETP 1.
Drop the database and create a new one.

SETP 1.
run the following command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate where your database is and delete the table. Then run *PHP artisan migrate* This worked for me