# Why can't I delete my WordPress database and how do I install a second database?

Tags: wordpress, installation, server, xampp

I'll start off by saying I know nothing about servers and the technical details of WordPress.

I had installed WordPress to one of my local hard drives so I can design two separate websites and test them both offline. However, when I try to connect, the browser displays a page that states there is an error and it cannot connect to the database.

I have not yet designed anything or otherwise created any content. Also, since I’m going to design two sites that will have different domain names, I decided, that I should have two separate WordPress installations on my one server (hard drive). But that was after I had already installed one set of the basic WordPress files (but no content yet for the site).

Given the errors and the fact that I hadn’t created any content, I decided it would be better to just uninstall all the WordPress files, then reinstall them from scratch. But now, the phpMyAdmin app (via XAMPP) will not allow me to drop (delete) the WordPress database. Please see the attached screenshot.

What should I do to 1. remove all traces of WordPress, then 2. install two separate copies of the WordPress package (in different folders) on my one hard drive?

[image: Database won't drop (delete) from phpMyAdmin (XAMPP)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Dropping Database (Can't rmdir '.test\', errno: 17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17)

Comment: Yes, Phil, that link answered my question on how to drop the database from phpMyAdmin. Thanks. Now it's time to create the two WordPress installations.